# Swift - How to display an image over the bar navigation

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uinavigationbar

My Api returns an url as string as banner image: [here](https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/banner/114308-VuYDoBJMbU1i.jpg)

In Swift, how to display this image over the bar navigation to achieve a result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set an UIImageView as the parent view, set necessary constraints so that it displays behind the UINavigationBar, and then set the image with the destined URL.